# How to pass a global variable before it gets rewritten to a fs.readFile in nodejs

Tags: node.js, callback

Update: I think I found the answer to a similar problem in here: [NodeJS readFile() retrieve filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681519/nodejs-readfile-retrieve-filename)

the point is that loops and have several call in http are actually kind of the same problem. The smartest solution may be to use ForEach instead of For

Hi I have the following code:

```
path = foo;
fs.readFile(path, function(err, data){

  do_something_with_data(data);
  do_something_with_path(path);


});
```

The problem is that the value of foo & path is overwritten with each single http request. So when the function do_something_with_path(path); is executed, the value of path is not the same as the one that was send as argument on fs.readFile(path ..

Is there anyway to use within fs.readFile the path value that was used instead of the last one?

Comment: are you using readFile in a loop..?

Comment: Thanks to Richard I may have a solution. What if I store an object as:
    object = {
      data: path,
    }

So then later I ask for the data and get the path related to it.

Comment: Not in a loop but on a http.server
Every time I got a http request the fs.readFile is executed. Meaning, when I sent an html document with several css, jpg... for each of them a new call to the fs.readFile is done. So within the fs.readFile when I execute the do_something_with_path(path); I just get the path of the last file requested.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a global variable. Instead, make a in-function variable. So whenever the function is called, a variable will be created which has something to do with this file.

Another try: use

```
var path = foo;
```

Comment: I don't get really the in-function variable. I can't create the variable within fs.readFile because the variable is the path passed as argument. I don't know if that's what you meant.

Comment: @AndresTapia by the way what's your context? Paste more code.

Comment: @AndresTapia try `var path = foo;`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable in another module then reference this from the file you are using `readFile`.

Create a `settings.js` file in your project root:

```
module.exports = {
    path: foo // Your variable
}
```

Inside your other js file where `fs.readFile` is being used.

```
var settings = require('../settings'); // Relative path to your settings file.
```

Then you can use `settings.path` as your global variable.

```
var settings = require('../settings');
path = foo;
fs.readFile(path, function(err, data){
  do_something_with_data(data);
  do_something_with_path(settings.path);
});
```

Comment: So basically you propose to store the value of path on an external module. I don't understand the difference between store it on a external module instead as in the same module. 
My problem was that the value of path is changing faster than the fs.readFile callback get executed. So wherever that value is stored it will be always faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use global keyword to store value of a variable globally

like following

```
global.path = foo;
```

It will store value globally.

Thanks